# Changing the target framework in an Azure web app

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I would like to publish an ASP.NET Core 2.1 website to Azure using an Azure Web App to host it. When creating the Azure Web App on the Azure portal, one of the settings is "Runtime Stack". In this case I would set it to ".NET Core 2.1" to match the framework my code is currently using. However once the web app is created, I do not see an option to edit this setting anywhere on the Azure portal, so how would I change it if necessary in the future?

For instance, if I were to later update my application code to use ASP.NET Core 2.2, how would I change the runtime stack of the Azure web app to ".NET Core 2.2"? Is there a setting to edit this in some area of the Azure portal? Or does the Azure web app look at the code (possibly the .csproj file), and automatically update the target framework internally, thus ignoring any settings anyway? Or would I need to delete the web app and create a new one with the correct settings? (If I would need to delete the web app and create a new one, is there some recommended approach to plan for this situation and reduce downtime? Would it be possible to update the staging slot to a newer runtime stack from the production slot, and then do a swap?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1 - Set the target framework for the project**

In the project set the target framework to the one you want. In VS, right click the project name, choose Properties, then specify the target framework.

[image]

Or directly edit the .csproj file to specify target framework, using the following syntax 
 `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>`

**Step 2 - Set the target framework for publishing**

When publishing the project, set the target framework there as well. In VS, right click the project name, choose Publish, and in the publish wizard specify the target framework.

[image]

This setting will be reflected in the .pubxml file as well (and can be edited there instead if you prefer using the syntax `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>` )

**Step 3 - Check that the runtime you need is present on Azure**

If the runtime version specified in the project and publish settings is present on Azure, then **that version will be used automatically**. So we need to check if it is present.

Alex described how to do this on Linux hosts in his answer but that does not work on Windows hosts (the 'Major Version' and 'Minor Version' settings are not displayed for Windows hosts on the Azure portal).

[image]

The Kudu console on the other hand works for both operating systems. Kudu can be reached at `https://<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net`. There are a couple of different ways to look up runtime versions Kudu -

Option 1. Click the 'Runtime versions' link in the Rest API section.

[image]
It will
    display the supported dotnetcore versions (and also nodejs versions,
    os version, etc).

Option 2. Click Debug Console -> CMD to launch the kudu
        command prompt. Type in `dotnet --list-runtimes`.

[image]

(Do not use `dotnet --list-sdks` because what is important is the runtime, not the sdk, since the sdk is needed for building an app and most likely you will build the app on your local machine before publishing to Azure).

**Step 4 - If the runtime is not present on Azure**

This might be the case if the runtime you are using is still in preview. You can either embed your own .net core version with the application or you can use an extension. These are described by Sebastien in his answer.

**Step 5 - Publish the app**

There is no need to delete the existing web app and create a new one. You can publish to an old app that was previously using a lower target framework.

Comment: Good instructions.  In my case, [Edit Target Framework] from the Publish page didn't take effect in VS.NET Community 2019 Version 16.4.6.  The edit dialog showed .Net Core 3.1 selected, but it still showed 3.0 when returning to Publish.  I had to text edit the *.pubxml file to change the target framework to 3.1.

Answer (score 29):

At least for Linux hosts, the runtime stack is available via the app service settings - it is just split up into multiple properties:

[image: General Settings]

On a more technical note, it can be accessed via `LinuxFxVersion`:

```json
    "siteProperties": {
      "metadata": null,
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "LinuxFxVersion",
          "value": "DOTNETCORE|2.1"
        },
        {
          "name": "WindowsFxVersion",
          "value": null
        }
      ],
      "appSettings": null
    },
```

E.g. via [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-set):

```
az webapp config set -g MyResourceGroup -n MyUniqueApp --linux-fx-version DOTNETCORE|2.1
```

If you want to avoid downtimes, you should use slots like you mentioned. Like every app deployment, you will have a very slow application for a short while during the deployment.

Changing everything in one go is possible if you use something like Azure Pipelines. The [Azure App Service Deploy Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) allows you to both deploy the application an set the runtime stack at the same time.

Slots are very much independent from each other, so you can have different runtime stacks depending on the slot.

Edit:
Some more additional information I came across in the meantime:

- You can find out the valid values for the runtime via `az webapp list-runtimes --os linux`
- There is also the `CURRENT_STACK` property in `siteconfig/metadata` which seems to influence the "Stack" setting on Windows hosts.

Answer (score 3):

Previous answer is correct, you can manage runtime version in Application Settings Configuration.

But, you can also run `dotnet publish --runtime win-x86` to embed your own .Net Core version with your application.
It adds some overhead but you control runtime version.

[.NET Core RID Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog)

A third option is to install a Site Extension

[image]